# What does eg %+% do? in R

Tags: r, operators

This is a very basic question - but apparently google is not very good at searching for strings like "%+%". So my question is - what and when is "%+%" and similar used. I guess its a kind of merge?.

EDIT: Ok - I believe my question is answered. %X% is binary operator of some kind. So now I think I will google around for knowledge about how/when to use these. My question was partly inspired by yesterday's question - but only after I saw this [post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/ggplot2-barplots/) on the "learning R" blog. The passage that gave rise to my question was this:
    In order to do this, a new dataframe with the annual totals will be created and later merged with the existing dataset (variable names in both dataframes should be identical for this to work). Then we just change the dataframe the plot is based on.

```
## add total immigration figures to the plot
total <- cast(df.m, Period ~ ., sum)
total <- rename(total, c("(all)" = "value"))
total$Region <- "Total"
df.m.t <- rbind(total, df.m)
c1 <- c %+% df.m.t
```

Comment: In the code example of your 'EDIT', you almost certainly want '+' and not '%+%'.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The ultimate reason is that if you do both general-purpose programming and numerical computations, it is useful to have a large complement of binary operators available. For example, if you store numbers in two-dimensional arrays, you may want to multiply the arrays elementwise, or you may want to compute the matrix product of two arrays. In Matlab these two operators are `.*` and `*`; in R they are `*` and `%*%`. Python has [resisted](https://peps.python.org/pep-0211/) [attempts](https://peps.python.org/pep-0225/) to add new operators, and so [numpy](https://numpy.org/) differentiates between the two kinds of product by having two classes: the array class is multiplied elementwise, the matrix class is multiplied in the linear-algebra sense.

Another example from Python is that for lists, plus means concatenation: `[1,2,3]+[4,5] == [1,2,3,4,5]`. But for numpy arrays, plus means elementwise addition: `array([1,2]) + array([4,5]) == array([5,7])`. If your code needs to do both, you have to convert between classes or use function notation, which can lead to cumbersome-looking code, especially where mathematics is involved.

So it would sometimes be convenient to have more operators available for use, and you might not know in advance what sorts of operators a particular application calls for. Therefore, the implementors of R have chosen to treat as operators anything named like `%foo%`, and several examples exist: `%in%` is set membership, `%x%` is Kronecker product, `%o%` is outer product. For an example of a language that has taken this to the extreme, see [Fortress](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716163013/http://projectfortress.sun.com/) (section 16 of the specification starts with the rules for operator names).

In the blog post you mentioned, the author is using the [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) graphing package, which defines `%+%` to mean some kind of combination of two plot elements. Really it seems to add a method to the bare `+` (which is a generic function so you can define what it means for user-defined objects), but it also defines `%+%` so that you can use the ggplot2 meaning of `+` (whatever it is) for other objects. If you install ggplot2, type `require(ggplot2)` and `` ?`%+%` `` to see the documentation of that operator, and `` methods(`+`) `` to see that a new definition has been added to `+`.

Comment: wauw - thank you so much Jouni! What an excellent answer -  it is all beginning to make sense now :-)

Comment: [Python 3.5 adds a new binary operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), `@`, which NumPy will use for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 15):

There is no generally defined `%+%`.  Maybe you looked at [this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319698/why-doesnt-operate-on-characters-in-r) where

```
R> '%+%' <- paste
R> "foo" %+% "bar"
[1] "foo bar"
R>
```

and ad-hoc string concatenation function was defined.    Generally, the 'percent-operator-percent' syntax is open for user-defined functions of two arguments, but there is (AFAIK) no generally accepted version for `%+%` that you can expect to be present everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my quick look at the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Function-calls) it may be a user defined infix operator, so, it's hard to tell what the actual meaning would be...

I would think binary addition.

Comment: Just the plain + is binary addition, I believe - %+% doesn't seem to have anything assigned to it.  Try ?Arithmetic for more information.