# What do the %op% operators in mean? For example "%in%"?

Tags: r, syntax, operators, r-faq

I tried to do this simple search but couldn't find anything on the percent (`%`) symbol in R.

**What does `%in%` mean in the following code?**

`time(x) %in% time(y)` where `x` and `y` are matrices.

**How do I look up help on `%in%` and similar functions** that follow the `%stuff%` pattern, as I cannot locate the help file?

Related questions:

- [What does eg %+% do? in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328903/what-does-eg-do-in-r)
- [The R %*% operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060515/the-r-operator)
- [What does %*% mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865094/what-does-mean-in-r)
- [What does %||% do in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190693/what-does-do-in-r)
- [What does %>% mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536154/what-does-mean-in-r)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328903/what-does-eg-do-in-r?rq=1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put quotes around it to find the help page.  Either of these work

```
> help("%in%")
> ?"%in%"
```

Once you get to the help page, you'll see that

> ‘%in%’ is currently defined as
>
> ‘"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0’

---

Since `time` is a generic, I don't know what `time(X2)` returns without knowing what `X2` is.  But, `%in%` tells you which items from the left hand side are also in the right hand side.

```
> c(1:5) %in% c(3:8)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

See also, `intersect`

```
> intersect(c(1:5), c(3:8))
[1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: So does: which(time(X2)%in%time(Y)) basically return the greater date between X2 and Y? Thanks to both for the answers

Comment: This does not answer original question, about %op% (custom infix operator), just answered the meaning of the example (what is not asked). ‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 58):

I didn't think GSee's or Sathish's answers went far enough because "%" *does* have meaning all by itself and not just in the context of the `%in%` operator. It is the mechanism for defining new infix operators by users. It is a much more general issue than the virtues of the `%in%` infix operator or its more general prefix ancestor `match`. It could be as simple as making a pairwise "s"(um) operator:

```
 `%s%` <- function(x,y) x + y
```

Or it could be more interesting, say making a second derivative operator:

```
 `%DD%` <- function(expr, nam="x") { D(D( bquote(.(expr)), nam), nam) }
 expression(x^4) %DD% "x"
 # 4 * (3 * x^2)
```

The `%`-character also has importance in the parsing of Date, date-time, and C-type format functions like `strptime`, `formatC` and `sprintf`.

Since that was originally written we have seen the emergence of the `magrittr` package with the `dplyr` elaboration that demonstrates yet another use for `%`-flanked operators.

So the most general answer is that `%` symbols are handled specially by the R parser. Since the parser is used to process plotmath expressions, you will also see extensive options for graphics annotations at the `?plotmath` help page.

Comment: Great explanation! Also, useful link: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/infix-operator/ Do you know any official documentation with an explanation of inflix operators?

Comment: Search in the R Language Definition for "Operators", "Group methods", "Special operators", and "Infix and prefix operators".

Answer (score 40):

`%op%` denotes an **[infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) [binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)**.  There are several built-in operators using `%`, and you can also create your own.

(A single `%` sign isn't a keyword in R. You can see a list of keywords on the [`?Reserved`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Reserved) help page.)

---

**How do I get help on binary operators?**

As with anything that isn't a standard variable name, you have to to enclose the term in quotes or backquotes.

```
?"%in%"
?`%in%`
```

Credit: [GSee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730667/134830).

---

**What does `%in%` do?**

As described on the `` ?`%in%` `` help page (which is actually the `?match` help page since `%in%` is really only an infix version of `match`.),

> [`%in%`] returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand

It is most commonly used with categorical variables, though it can be used with numbers as well.

```
c("a", "A") %in% letters
## [1]  TRUE FALSE

1:4 %in% c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Credit: [GSee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730667/134830), [Ari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731480/134830), [Sathish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731221/134830).

---

**How do I create my own infix binary operators?**

These are functions, and can be defined in the same way as any other function, with a couple of restrictions.

1. It's a *binary* opertor, so the function must take exactly two arguments.
2. Since the name is non-standard, it must be written with quotes or backquotes.

For example, this defines a matrix power operator.

```
`%^%` <- function(x, y) matrixcalc::matrix.power(x, y)

matrix(1:4, 2) %^% 3
```

Credit: [BondedDust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731591/134830), [Ari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731480/134830).

---

**What other `%` operators are there?**

In **base R:**

`%/%` and `%%` perform [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers) and [modular division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) respectively, and are described on the [`?Arithmetic`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Arithmetic) help page.

[`%o%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/outer) gives the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of arrays.

[`%*%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/matmult) performs [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

[`%x%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/kronecker) performs the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of arrays.

In **[ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/):**

[`%+%`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/gg-add.html) replaces the data frame in a ggplot.

`%+replace%` modifies theme elements in a ggplot.

`%inside%` (internal) checks for values in a range.

`%||%` (internal) provides a default value in case of `NULL` values.  This function also appears internally in devtools, reshape2, roxygen2 and knitr.  (In knitr it is called `%n%`.)

In **[magrittr](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr):**

`%>%` pipes the left-hand side into an expression on the right-hand side.

`%<>%` pipes the left-hand side into an expression on the right-hand side, and then assigns the result back into the left-hand side object.

`%T>%` pipes the left-hand side into an expression on the right-hand side, which it uses only for its side effects, returning the left-hand side.

`%,%` builds a functional sequence.

`%$%` exposes columns of a data.frame or members of a list.

In **data.table:**

[`%between%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/topics/between) checks for values in a range.

[`%chin%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/chmatch) is like `%in%`, optimised for character vectors.

[`%like%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/like) checks for regular expression matches.

In **Hmisc:**

`%nin%` returns the opposite of `%in%`.

In **devtools**:

`%:::%` (internal) gets a variable from a namespace passed as a string.

In **[sp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html)**:

[`%over%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/over-methods) performs a spatial join (e.g., which polygon corresponds to some points?)

In **rebus**:

`%R%` concatenates elements of a `regex` object.

In [**lubridate**](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/index.html):

[`%m+%`/`%m-%`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lubridate/html/mplus.html) add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month

[`%--%`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/interval.html) For creation and manipulation of 'Interval' objects

[`%within%`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html) Check if a date (or interval) fall within an interval

---

More generally, you can find all the operators in all the packages installed on your machine using:

```
library(magrittr)

ip <- installed.packages() %>% rownames
(ops <- setNames(ip, ip) %>% 
  lapply(
    function(pkg)
    {
      rdx_file <- system.file("R", paste0(pkg, ".rdx"), package = pkg)
      if(file.exists(rdx_file))
      {
        rdx <- readRDS(rdx_file)
        fn_names <- names(rdx$variables)
        fn_names[grepl("^%", fn_names)]
      }
    }
  ) %>% 
  unlist
)
```

Comment: Superb summary. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

More generally, `%foo%` is the syntax for a binary operator.  Binary operators in R are really just functions in disguise, and take two arguments (the one before and the one after the operator become the first two arguments of the function).

For example:

```
> `%in%`(1:5,4:6)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

While `%in%` is defined in base R, you can also define your own binary function:

```
`%hi%` <- function(x,y) cat(x,y,"\n")
> "oh" %hi% "my"
oh my
```

Comment: another such user defined binary operator is %*% which does true matrix multiplication, whereas the operator * does only vectorized computation of data.

Comment: @Sathish Noted, although I'd call %*%, %in%, etc. "non-user-defined" or "built-in" operators.

Comment: This straightforwardness of this answer was surprisingly helpful, despite understanding the higher rated answers

Answer (score 2):

`%in%` is an operator used to find and subset multiple occurrences of the same name or value in a matrix or data frame.

For example 1: subsetting with the same name

```
set.seed(133)
x <- runif(5)
names(x) <- letters[1:5]
x[c("a", "d")]
#  a         d 
#  0.5360112 0.4231022
```

Now you change the name of "d" to "a"

```
 names(x)[4] <- "a"
```

If you try to extract the similar names and its values using the previous subscript, it will not work. Notice the result, it does not have the elements of [1] and [4].

```
x[c("a", "a")]

#        a         a 
#    0.5360112 0.5360112
```

So, you can extract the two "a"s from different position in a variable by using `%in%` binary operator.

```
names(x) %in% "a"
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#assign it to a variable called "vec"
 vec <- names(x) %in% "a"

#extract the values of two "a"s
 x[vec]
 #         a         a 
 #  0.5360112 0.4231022
```

Example 2: Subsetting multiple values from a column
Refer [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm) for an example