# Error in R: nonconformable arguments. Not true?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

this is my code:

```
    #define likelihood function (including an intercept/constant in the function.)
lltobit <- function(b,x,y) {
  sigma <-  b[3]
  y  <- as.matrix(y)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  vecones <- rep(1,nrow(x)) 
  x <- cbind(vecones,x)
  bx <- x %*% b[1:2] 
  d <- y != 0 
  llik <- sum(d * ((-1/2)*(log(2*pi) + log(sigma^2) + ((y - bx)/sigma)^2)) 
              + (1-d) * (log(1 - pnorm(bx/sigma))))
  return(-llik)
}

n <- nrow(censored) #define number of variables 
y <- censored$y #define y and x for easier use
x1 <- as.matrix(censored$x)
x <-  cbind(rep(1,n),x1) #include constant/intercept 
bols <- (solve(t(x) %*% x)) %*% (t(x) %*% y) #compute ols estimator (XX) -1 XY
init <- rbind(as.matrix(bols[1:nrow(bols)]),1) #initial values 

init

tobit1 <- optim(init, lltobit, x=x, y=y, hessian=TRUE, method="BFGS")
```

where censored is my data table, including 200 (censored) values of y and 200 values of x.

Everything works, but when running the optim command, i get the following error:

```
tobit1 <- optim(init, lltobit, x=x, y=y, hessian=TRUE, method="BFGS")
Error in x %*% b[1:2] : non-conformable arguments
```

I know what it means, but since x is a 200 by 2 matrix, and b[1:2] a vector of 2 by 1, what goes wrong? I tried transposing both, and also the initial values vector, but nothing works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your function, the line `x <- cbind(vecones,x)` adds a column to `x`. Since you are passing a two columns matrix, the new `x` will have 3 columns and then cannot be multiplied to `b[1:2]`.

Comment: If R tells you have non-conformable arguments, you can believe it.

Comment: @nicola No, originally x has only 1 column/it is a vector. Adding this extra column of ones, implies we now have 2.

Comment: @Pascal I know R won't lie to me, but nobody seems to be able to find the mistake in my code/why the error occurs. As far as I know, I can multiply a 200x2 by a 2x1.

Comment: @pvb1995 you are wrong. Execute your code. See that before calling `optim`, `x` is a `matrix` (can you see the `x <-  cbind(rep(1,n),x1)` line?). Than, when `x` is passed to `lltobit`, another column is added and then the error.

Comment: @nicola thanks let me try this

Comment: @nicola it works! I only needed the matrix x before, for the initial values, and the original x vector for the optim. thanks for showing me

Answer (score 17):

I stumbled upon a similar problem today ("non-conformable arguments" error, even though everything seemed OK), and solution in my case was in basic rules for matrix-multiplication: i.e. number of **columns** of the **left** matrix must be the same as the number of **rows** of the **right** matrix = I had to switch order in multiplication equation.
In other words, in matrix multiplication (unlike ordinary multiplication), `A %*% B` is not the same as `B %*% A`.

Answer (score 0):

I offer one case in Principal Component Regression (PCR) in R, today I met this problem when tring to fit test data with model. it returned an error:

```
> pcr.pred = predict(pcr.fit, test.data, ncomp=6)
Error in newX %*% B[-1, , i] : non-conformable arguments
In addition: Warning message:
```

The problem was that, the test data has a new level that is previously not contained in the train data. To find which level has the problem:

```
cols = colnames(train)
for (col in cols){
  if(class(ori.train[[col]]) == 'factor'){
    print(col)
    print(summary(train[[col]]))
    print(summary(test[[col]]))
  }
}
```

You can check which annoying attributes has this new level, then you can replace this 'new' attribute with other common values, save the data with `write.csv` and reload it, and you can run the PCR prediction.