# Error in VAR model

Tags: r, dplyr, var, forecasting

I have this data:

```
     Year W  L  PTS GF  GA  S    SA
1    2006 49 25 106 253 224 2380 2662
2    2007 51 23 110 266 207 2261 2553
3    2008 41 32 91  227 224 2425 2433
4    2009 40 34 88  207 228 2375 2398
5    2010 47 29 100 217 221 2508 2389
6    2011 44 27 99  213 190 2362 2506
7    2012 48 26 104 232 205 2261 2517
8    2014 38 32 88  214 233 2382 2365
9    2015 47 25 104 226 202 2614 2304
10   2016 41 27 96  224 213 2507 2231
11   2017 41 29 94  238 220 2557 2458
12   2018 53 18 117 261 204 2641 2650
```

I've built a VAR model from this data (it's hockey data for one team for the listed years). I converted the above into a time series the `ts()` argument, and created this model:

```
VARselect(NSH_ts[, 3:5], lag.max = 8)
var1 <- VAR(NSH_ts[, 3:5], p = 2, type = "both", ic = c("AIC"))
serial.test(var1, type = "PT.adjusted")
forecast.var1 <- forecast(var1, h = 2) 
autoplot(forecast.var1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2006, 2022))
```

I want to use the `serial.test()` argument, but I get this error:

```
Error in t(Ci) %*% C0inv : non-conformable arguments
```

Why won't the `serial.test()` argument work? (Overall I'm trying to forecast `PTS` for the next two years, based on the variables in the set).

I've been using this as a guide: https://otexts.org/fpp2/VAR.html

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated because the issue is really a statistical one: you are trying to fit a model which is much too complex for the amount of data that you have. In a VAR model, you end up losing p dates at the beginning, which means that for p=2 you only really have 10 data points. For 3 series, you'll need 18 parameters for the autoregressive part alone, plus another 2 x 3 for the constant/trend (`type = both`).

Comment: So you are saying I don't have enough data to fit a VAR model, from the sample data given? That would clarify things.

Comment: You could fit a VAR model with fewer parameters, for example by including fewer lags, by imposing restrictions on some of the coefficients, or by using fewer exogenous regressors (i.e. the constant/trend). You should also decrease `lag.max` when calling `VARselect` to a more reasonable level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting a different error, which may be from the `VARselect`. My table is mostly `-Inf` entries, with one `NaN`, and the rest 0. Adjusting the `lag.max` gave me real numbers, and I had to adjust the other values as well.

```
VARselect(dfVAR[, 3:5], lag.max = 2)
var1 <- VAR(dfVAR[, 3:5], p = 1, type = "both", ic = c("AIC"))
serial.test(var1, lags.pt = 4, type = "PT.adjusted")

    Portmanteau Test (adjusted)

data:  Residuals of VAR object var1
Chi-squared = 35.117, df = 27, p-value = 0.1359
```

[The basis of the non-conformable error is that your matrix algebra isn't working, the number of cols in the first matrix have to match the number of rows in the second.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425930/2359523) Having no knowledge of `VAR` models, I can't offer help beyond this.

Comment: For the models to be comparable, `VARselect` must use the same sample for each p, which means that you lose 8 points if that's your `lag.max`, independently of p, leaving only 4 points to fit your model. That's why you get a bunch of nonsense.