# Where can I find more info on %>%

Tags: r

I'd like to learn more information on %>% in R programming.

I have tried googling and researching the issue but have come up empty handed.

I have also searched overflorw but no information was found.

Any links or resources would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's from the magrittr package. Some package you're using requires/imports it. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Comment: Check out https://github.com/smbache/magrittr

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314680/how-to-use-the-formerly-the-operator-in-r

Comment: google 'piping in r'

Comment: you should have searched within r itself: `?'%>%'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does %>% function mean in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r)

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the [magrittr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html), where the link to the left provides an excellent introduction.

The `%>%` is beginning to be incorporated into other packages, although it can be used with any functions to pipe the output into the first argument input to a second function.  The `%>%` operator can also be chained.