# What does %*% mean in R

Tags: r

I am following some [code](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/canonical.htm) and I can apply everything until I get to the command:

```
s1 %*% cc1$xcoef
```

This line does not work for me and I can't find documentation to explain it's purpose. I get this error:

```
Error in s1 %*% cc1$xcoef : non-conformable arguments
```

What does the `%*%` do and can I use another function?

I am using R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) "Warm Puppy"

Comment: Look at [`?"%*%"`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/matmult.html) to read the helpfile.

Comment: Thanks I forgot the quotes when using ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `?'%*%'` to get the documentation.

`%*%` is matrix multiplication.  For matrix multiplication, you need an `m x n` matrix times an `n x p` matrix.

Comment: Your answer taught me that I can use quotation marks after `?` to find documentation on other arithmetic operators in R too, like `?"%%".

Answer (score 24):

matrix multiplication, see the following example:

```
> A <- matrix (c(1,3,4, 5,8,9, 1,3,3), 3,3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    3    8    3
[3,]    4    9    3
> 
> B <- matrix (c(2,4,5, 8,9,2, 3,4,5), 3,3)
> 
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8    3
[2,]    4    9    4
[3,]    5    2    5
> 
> 
> A %*% B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   27   55   28
[2,]   53  102   56
[3,]   59  119   63

> B %*% A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   38  101   35
[2,]   47  128   43
[3,]   31   86   26
```

Also see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

If this does not follow the size of matrix rule you will get the error:

```
> A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 3,2)
    > A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

> B <- matrix (c(3,1,3,4,4,4,4,4,3), 3,3)

> B
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    3    4    4
    [2,]    1    4    4
    [3,]    3    4    3
    > A%*%B
    Error in A %*% B : non-conformable arguments
```