# How to multiply two matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I hve two matrices . One of the matrix is  3x1 and another one is 3x3 matrix. How could I multiply them in R ?

Comment: `A %*% B`   see     `?'%*%'`

Comment: Going to add this link for future searchers: how to use `%*%` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865094/what-does-mean-in-r

Comment: Umm... you can't multiply a 3x1 matrix by 3x3 matrix? Try 1x3 matrix by 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are the matrices
Matrix multiplication: A %*% B