# What does %||% do in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run some [R code from github](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/install-github.r), however these functions use a command `%||%`, that doesn't seem to be in base R. What exactly does this function do and what packages, if any, do I need to get it to work on my machine? As you can imagine, this particular string is un-Google-able since it's entirely special characters.

Comment: usually seen it defined as an analogue to the ruby `||` operator, as in [hadley's ggplot code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/utilities.r#L1:L9)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/utils.r

```
"%||%" <- function(a, b) if (!is.null(a)) a else b
```

It's an internal function, so you probably need to redefine it for yourself if you want to use it outside the package.

```
"%||%" <- devtools:::`%||%`
1 %||% NULL
## [1] 1
NULL %||% 2
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Whoops, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!