# R: How does the regex "\\b"%s+%c("character","...")%s+%"\\b" work?

Tags: r, regex, replaceall, stringi

I was looking for an option to replace multiple patterns and found some answers in the first of below links. One of the suggested answers uses the `stringr` package. I was interested to check options with `stringi` and found one in the documentation (last example of second link) which is:

```
stri_replace_all_regex("The quicker brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
 "\\b"%s+%c("quick", "brown", "fox")%s+%"\\b", c("slow",  "black", "bear"), vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Could someone explain how the `%s+%` works here. I know about options to use `%`, see, e.g., related questions mentioned in link 3 below. However, I could not figure out how this specific syntax works. Does this relate to piping, formatting (e.g. like in `sprintf`), or the space regex? Could someone please explain how this works or point me to a resource where I can inform myself? I wasn´t sure what the meta-topic was, so I did not know where to look at in, e.g., regex manuals? Sorry, if this is an easy one and it turns out that I have just applied the wrong search strategy. Thank you.

My questions relates to the following links:

[1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector)

[2: http://www.gagolewski.com/software/stringi/manual/?manpage=stri_replace](http://www.gagolewski.com/software/stringi/manual/?manpage=stri_replace)

[3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730629/what-do-the-op-operators-in-mean-in-r-for-example-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730629/what-do-the-op-operators-in-mean-in-r-for-example-in)

Comment: take a look at `?"%s+%"`. It concatenates two character vectors, so basically does the same as `paste0()`.

Comment: How embarrassing. That was an easy one. Thank you for pointing me to the answer.