# How can I iterate the levels of a factor in R?

Tags: r, r-factor

I would like to create a function that helps me to identify possible mistakes in the levels of a factor by accessing the first letter, so first I am focused on the identification part.

**Data Frame**
'''

```
alleles<-(c('A*24:02', 'A*11:01', 'blank',  'A*31:01'))
as.factor(alleles)
freq<-c(0.3782, 0.4209, 0.0362, 0.0761)

df<-data.frame(alleles, freq)
```

'''

**My attempt**_
'''

```
for(i in df$alleles){
  if (i != 'A'){
    can<-c()
    append(can, i)
    df$alleles<-df$alleles[-c(can)]
  }
}
```

'''
***Error message***
Error in -c(can) : invalid argument to unary operator

***Observations***
If I do '''print(can)''' the output is "NULL" meaning that it is not working the use of "append".

Comment: Please provide your expected result.  It's a little difficult to understand what your code is supposed to do.  If you just want the first character in `alleles`, you can use `substr(df$alleles, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:

```
#Data
alleles<-(c('A*24:02', 'A*11:01', 'blank',  'A*31:01'))
freq<-c(0.3782, 0.4209, 0.0362, 0.0761)
df<-data.frame(alleles, freq)
can<-c()
#Check
for(i in 1:length(df$alleles))
{
  if (substr(df$alleles[i],1,1) != 'A'){
    can <- c(can, as.character(df$alleles[i]))
  }
}
#Apply
df<-df[-which(df$alleles %in% can),]
```

Output:

```
df
  alleles   freq
1 A*24:02 0.3782
2 A*11:01 0.4209
4 A*31:01 0.0761
```

Comment: It's incredible, thank you so much! I was wondering if you can tell me how to find the documentation of '%in%. I have typed '?<backtick>%in%<backtick>' but it doesn't work

Comment: @Christ14n97 Try <backtick>? in<backtick>

Comment: @Christ14n97 Also check this post about that operator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730629/what-do-the-op-operators-in-mean-for-example-in

Comment: I appreciate so much your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a regular expressions?

```
df[grepl("^A", df$alleles),]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
df[grep("^A", df$alleles),]
```