# Making a string concatenation operator in R

Tags: string, r, string-concatenation

I was wondering how one might go about writing a string concatenation operator in R, something like || in SAS, + in Java/C# or & in Visual Basic.

The easiest way would be to create a special operator using %, like

```
`%+%` <- function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep="")
```

but this leads to lots of ugly `%`'s in the code.

I noticed that `+` is defined in the Ops group, and you can write S4 methods for that group, so perhaps something like that would be the way to go. However, I have no experience with S4 language features at all. How would I modify the above function to use S4?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319698/why-doesnt-operate-on-characters-in-r

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-February/066719.html

Comment: Note : `\`%+%\` = paste0` works the same as OP's implementation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you cannot override the sealed S4 method "+". However, you do not need to define a new class in order to define an addition function for strings; this is not ideal since it forces you to convert the class of strings and thus leading to more ugly code. Instead, one can simply overwrite the "+" function:

```
"+" = function(x,y) {
    if(is.character(x) || is.character(y)) {
        return(paste(x , y, sep=""))
    } else {
        .Primitive("+")(x,y)
    }
}
```

Then the following should all work as expected:

```
1 + 4
1:10 + 4 
"Help" + "Me"
```

This solution feels a bit like a hack, since you are no longer using formal methods but its the only way to get the exact behavior you wanted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with S3/4 that much - what exactly is hacky about this? Seem to work pretty well.

Comment: This is an old post but I have a feeling a lot of people still look at it. I would make one suggestion to make the use of this function more constrained. Change the logical operator in the if statement to &. I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to concat two objects if you're only sure one of them is a string. The resulting error message would not be as intuitive as compared to the error message you'd get from the primitive +.

Comment: @JoshBradley: I reverted your edit because there was no error if different object types were concatenated. The non-character argument is promoted to character, which is consistent with many other R functions. R is not a strongly typed language and `Primitive("+")` does allow mixed types (e.g. `TRUE+1L`, `1L+1.0`). I suggest you add your own answer, rather than changing the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer break several other packages that define their own methods for the plus operator. Most prominently ggplot2. I'd advise against its usage

Comment: It does not break ggplot2 for me. ggplot2 defines its "+" as an S3 method for class "gg". See `?ggplot2::`%+%``.

Comment: will this hack possibly slow down some other code, that might use "+" operator?

Comment: I retract my previous statement about ggplot but it does slow down execution by about 6 percent. Try `microbenchmark({1:10000 + 1:10000})` with primitive `+` and with this `+`. So I was reluctant to add it to my default pipeline

Comment: Great ! you can even write `"foo"+"1"+0` with 0 as numeric

Answer (score 29):

I'll try this (relatively more clean S3 solution)

```
`+` <- function (e1, e2) UseMethod("+")
`+.default` <- function (e1, e2) .Primitive("+")(e1, e2)
`+.character` <- function(e1, e2) 
    if(length(e1) == length(e2)) {
           paste(e1, e2, sep = '')
    } else stop('String Vectors of Different Lengths')
```

Code above will change `+` to a generic, and set the `+.default` to the original `+`, then add new method `+.character` to `+`

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why demanding that the two strings have the same length ?

Comment: The test is not that strings have identical length. It tests whether the vectors have the same length. ie, `"baz" + "foobar"` is fine, `"baz" + c("foo", "bar")` is not.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use S3 classes for this:

```
String <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("String", class(x))
  x
}

"+.String" <- function(x,...) {
  x <- paste(x, paste(..., sep="", collapse=""), sep="", collapse="")
  String(x)
}


print.String <- function(x, ...) cat(x)

x <- "The quick brown "
y <- "fox jumped over "
z <- "the lazy dog"

String(x) + y + z
```

Answer (score 13):

If R would thoroghlly comply with S4, the following would have been enough:

```
setMethod("+",
          signature(e1 = "character", e2 = "character"),
          function (e1, e2) {
              paste(e1, e2, sep = "")
      })
```

But this gives an error that the method is sealed :((. Hopefully this will change in the feature versions of R.

The best you can do is to define new class "string" which would behave exactly as "character" class:

```
setClass("string", contains="character")
string <- function(obj) new("string", as.character(obj))
```

and define the most general method which R allows:

```
setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "character", e2 = "ANY"),
          function (e1, e2) string(paste(e1, as.character(e2), sep = "")))
```

now try:

```
tt <- string(44444)

tt
#An object of class "string"
#[1] "44444"
tt + 3434
#[1] "444443434"
"sfds" + tt
#[1] "sfds44444"
tt +  tt
#[1] "4444444444"
343 + tt
#Error in 343 + tt : non-numeric argument to binary operator
"sdfs" + tt + "dfsd"
#An object of class "string"
#[1] "sdfs44444dfsd"
```

Answer (score 9):

You have given yourself the correct answer -- everything in R is a function, and you cannot define new operators. So `%+%` is as good as it gets.

Comment: But you can redefine the behavior of existing operators. Not in this case though because the "+" methods is sealed for signature c("character", "character").