# loop in R language with variable in address

Tags: r, for-loop

I have several txt files, and their names are 1.txt, 2.txt,3.txt and … 100.txt

I want to read these files in R language in loop. My code is:

```
For(I in 1:100){

    Datai<-read.table(“H://”+’i’+”.txt”)

}
```

But when I run I get this error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For(I in 1:100){

Datai<-read.table(paste(paste("H://",i,".txt",sep="")))

}
```

As far as I know there is no string concatenate operator in R.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r) is a question how to construct one.

Comment: A single paste should do also the trick `paste("H://",i,".txt",sep="")`

Answer (score 1):

In your loop the object `Datai` is replaced by the new object in each run. You should store the data frames returned by `read.table` in a list instead.

```
Data <- vector("list", length = 100) # initialize the list
For(I in 1:100){    
    Data[[I]] <- read.table(paste("H://", I, ".txt", sep = ""))    
}
```

The same could be achieved with `lapply`:

```
Data <- lapply(1:100, function(I) read.table(paste("H://", I, ".txt", sep = "")))
```