# How is ggplot2 plus operator defined?

Tags: r, ggplot2, operators

The `+` usually throws `non-numeric argument to binary operator` when provided with something other than a number. But it works with ggplot2, pasting the plot together. At the same time, it retains its usual function outside of the context of ggplot2 (e.g. as an arithmetic or formula operator), so its ggplot2 version is not in conflict with either of these.

I wish to understand how to make the `+` behave this way. Browsing the ggplot2 github repo, I have found function definitions for `+.gg` and `%+%` but it did not make things clearer for me.

I would be happy with a pointer to the code in ggplot2 package that does this, or a generalized explanation of how this is done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you dissect `+.gg` we have:

```
> ggplot2:::`+.gg`
function (e1, e2) 
{
  e2name <- deparse(substitute(e2))
  if (is.theme(e1)) 
    add_theme(e1, e2, e2name)
  else if (is.ggplot(e1)) 
    add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
}
```

Besides, `add_theme`, what you're interested in is is `add_ggplot` which can be accessed with `ggplot2:::add_ggplot`. The latter - a long yet very organized function - reveals more "cascading" functions to dispatch what's meant to be added.

That being said, R "knows" when using "+" on an object of class `gg` which function to apply (because of [S3 classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html)). You can find the starting point in `ggplot2` GitHub repos, in the [`ggproto.R`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/ggproto.r) on which I think most of `ggplot2` behaviour depends on.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. What is not clear to me is that the name of the function is `+.gg`, but we don't use `+.gg`, we use simple `+`. How does R know to call `+.gg`, if that is what's happening?

Comment: That's because of [S3 classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html). And anything being a function call in R (try `+` (with quotes)), `ggplot2` "simply" extends the `+` method to object of class `gg`.

Comment: Hmm, seeing the `.` in there now, this should have pointed me in the right direction! Would you happen to know where the definition of the class is in the ggplot2 repo?

Comment: you mean the `gg` class or the `+.gg` method?

Comment: The class. It does not appear to be in the [same file](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot-construction.r) as the method.

Comment: I think most of it relies on [`ggproto`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/ggproto.r) but not 100% sure.

Comment: I've been stressing over this all day :-)   Thanks to both the question and the answer.  Coming from other languages, I tried looking for "operator overloading" initially, but that went nowhere, perhaps since it's considered a different concept.   I think the linked "S3 Classes" document is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If I define `(backtick)+.character(backtick) <- paste0`, `'a'+'b'` doesn't work. Why is it so?

Comment: @chan1142 This is because operators like `+` only dispatch s3 on objects with an actual "class" attribute. True, `class("a")` returns `"character"`, but if you check `attributes("a")` you get NULL. If you define e.g. `a <- structure("a", class = "character")` and do the same for `b` too, it will work. See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/104751.html and also, this one for how to work around it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18175871/2416535

Comment: @jakub Super! Thanks!!!