# "demask" function by finding its definition from previously loaded package

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my package, I define `%+%` operator as a shortcut for strings concatenation. As it may be defined by previously loaded packages, I want to execute my custom code only when both arguments are suitable (e.g. character), otherwise try to call the code from previously loaded packages. Here is my solution for that:

```
# helper function to find environment of the package
getEnvByName <- function(inpEnv=.GlobalEnv, lookFor){
  e <- inpEnv;
  while (environmentName(e) != 'R_EmptyEnv' & environmentName(e)!=lookFor) e <- parent.env(e);
  if (environmentName(e) != lookFor) return(NULL);
  return(e);
}

"%+%" <- function(arg1, arg2){
  if (is.character(arg1) & is.character(arg2)) {
    paste0(arg1, arg2);
  } else {
    e <- parent.env(getEnvByName(.GlobalEnv,'package:mypackagename'));
    if (exists('%+%', envir = e)) get('%+%',envir = e)(arg1,arg2);
  } 
}
```

My questions are:
1) is it a good way to treat such situations?
2) why it is not the common practice to do similar things in other packages? For example, in the `ggplot2` package, `%+%` operator is defined as following:

```
"%+%" <- function (e1, e2) 
{
    e2name <- deparse(substitute(e2))
    if (is.theme(e1)) add_theme(e1, e2, e2name)
    else if (is.ggplot(e1)) add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
}
```

as you see, their code breaks previously defined `%+%` for any arguments while they could just override it only for `theme` or `ggplot` arguments and keep all other cases. I could suggest the authors to implement this kind of check but I assume there's some reason they don't do it...

UPD. just a little modification of my code: instead of defining everything in one function, I split it with `UseMethod()` - I'm wondering if it makes any difference:

```
`%+%` <- function(...) UseMethod("%+%")
`%+%.character` <- paste0
`%+%.default` <- function (arg1, arg2){
  e <- parent.env(getEnvByName(.GlobalEnv,'package:mypackagename'));
  get('%+%',envir = e)(arg1,arg2);
}
```

Comment: i think the standard approach is to define a generic function, and your specific method. Since you want dispatch to happen for more than one argument, that would probably require S4.

Comment: not sure I understand it correctly :/ could you explain a bit more? Thanks!!!

Comment: to be honest I'm not qualified to answer, that was just a pointer in the direction of S4 classes.

Comment: ok, thanks for your input! I will check that.

Comment: Why not just make it `%s+%` or import that from `stringi`? Also, this may be a dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r

Comment: well, for me it's not really a dup - I have read that question. Solution with redefining `+` works indeed but I wanted to avoid modifying operator that is so widely used. `%s+%` etc works as well but for me it's rather a workaround, while my question is more generally about the case when we really want to keep the same name...

Comment: I'm guessing the answer lies somewhere around `setGenericImplicit`, `setOldClass`, and some other tricks to make a S3-S4 bridge, but there seem to be few people using S4 on these forums. You may have better luck on the R-help list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think it is a good practice to reimplement functions that already exist in widely used package (I refer to previously mentioned `%s+%` from `stringi`).

As for about you question I think the best way is this:

```
'%+%' <- function(arg1, arg2){
  if (is.character(arg1) & is.character(arg2)) {
    paste0(arg1, arg2)
  } else {
    old.func <- get('%+%',
                    envir = parent.env(.GlobalEnv),
                    inherits = TRUE)
    old.func(arg1, arg2)
  } 
}
```

1. With option `inherits = TRUE` (which is default by the way) `get` performs the same search in environments as is implemented in your answer;
2. The method with `UseMethod` will work differently because in that case `%+%` will check only the first argument for the type "character", not both arguments;
3. As for `ggplot2`s `%+%` I think it was intended to return `NULL` with not suitable arguments' type. It might possibly be a flaw in the code.

Comment: 1. You're right that I don't need to loop through all environments (it's actually piece of a code I used to locate the specific environment where the function was defined first), I will probably remove this part from my question. However, your code is not totally correct either - it finds the function itself and goes to infinite recursion. Instead of `parent.env(.GlobalEnv)`, it should be `parent.env(parent.env(.GlobalEnv))`.

Comment: 2. Checking the `character` type is kinda obvious, I meant if there's any other difference. Imagine if my first variant I only check the first argument - what will be the difference then.  
3. Not sure if returning `NULL` is intended by purpose, but anyway - that's what breaks the functioning of previously loaded functions, and it's so easy to avoid, so my main question is - what is the reason of not doing that.

Comment: I checked on two machines (on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04) and my code with only one `parent.env` returns function `%+%` from `ggplot2` (if this package loaded, of course). Strange...

Comment: maybe it's because you define it not from the package

Comment: Yes, I think that is the reason. But then the method with two `parent.env` also not very good because this package can be not the last loaded. There is a need for using logic that omits current package in consecutive search up through environments.

Comment: ouch, you're right, thanks for pointing out! I have added the code to find the environment of my package (not sure if it's a good solution but I couldn't find anything like `getEnvByName()` functionality).