# '+' operator to support non numeric arguments in r

Tags: r

The "+" supports `numeric`, `integer` and `Date` in `r`. All below operations are valid.

```
> 5 + 5L
[1] 10
> Sys.Date() + 5
[1] "2018-01-18"
```

But `+` doesn't work between `character`. Like:

```
> "one" + "one"
Error in "one" + "one" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> "What is date today? Ans:" + Sys.Date()
Error in unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is it forbidden to allow other than `numeric` argument in `r`? Or someone can overwrite `+` behavior to support other types of argument.

Comment: What do you expect `"one" + "one"` to result in?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was looking for substitute of  `paste`. That means, I was expecting `"oneone"`.

Comment: Why is this behaviour inconsistent? What do you expect `"one"+"two"` to deliver? It just is not defined for character arguments.

Comment: Well just use `paste`.

Comment: @MKR Oh, so string concatenation. R creators seem to have chosen for `+` to he used solely for numeric uses. Doesn't seem inconsistent.

Comment: @Bhas Yes. `paste` is available but sometime I miss that capability. esp. while using from command line in `RStudio`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Agree. Title of issue is not appropriate. There is no consistency. Rather I'm looking for additional feature.

Comment: `\`%+%\` <- function(e1, e2) paste0(e1, e2); "one" %+% "one"` This has been asked before.

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks Rich. It seems solution from `aocall` is more elegant.

Comment: ... which is also the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r/30649288#30649288) on that question.

Comment: @RichScriven yes. I should have done some more research before asking it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could redefine `+`, though I don't recommend it.

```
`+` <- function(x, y) UseMethod("+")
`+.character` <- function(x, y) paste0(x, y)
`+.default` <- .Primitive("+")

1 + 1 ##2
"a" + "b" ##"ab"
"a" + 2 ##"a2"
```

Comment: I do wonder why R's core team never added it to R itself...