# Build new operation function in R package

Tags: r, package, magrittr

I already read the tutorial about create the new package in R. I can use my custom function after clean and rebuild button in Rstudio. Now I want to create custom operation like `%>%` in the **magrittr** pacakge, so I define the function blow in the `function.r`, I want my `+` function can paste two string like python.

```
`+` = function(x, y){
  if( is.character(x) & is.character(y) ){
    return( paste0(x, y) )
  }else{
    `+` <- base::`+`
    return( x + y )
  }
}
```

When I clean and rebuild, I can not find this function in my package, also can not use this function.
But it successful by using the `source("function.r")` to call the function.
How do I create the operation function in my package like **magrittr** pacakge?

Here is my package folder blow:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jse3qamEg_wsYLrZDd-nekGbqPMi8f76/view?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad and inefficient approach. You should not mask + if you care about performance at all. If you absolutely have to, I'd use this approach instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649288/1412059

Comment: Did you export the function ?

Comment: After export in the NAMESPACE file, it work.