# Overloading `$` for named vector in R

Tags: r

When working with named vectors like

```
vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2)
```

I often find myself introducing mistakes by writing `vec$a` when I should be writing `vec["a"]` or `vec[["a"]]` to access the corresponding value with and without the name, respectively.

I think `vec$a` being an error is counter-intuitive, as `$` generally extracts named things. This feeling even seems supported e.g. in `?Extract`, where the example usage is `x$name` - isn't that a perfect fit for a *named* vector?

That got me thinking about the possibility of overloading the `$` operator to work on named vectors. However, I am not very experienced with operator overloading in R, and I understand (e.g. from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322546/operation-overloading-in-r)) that caution is advised when overloading basic operators.

My interconnected questions: **Is there a reason why I shouldn't overload `$` as described** that I'm failing to understand? That is, **is there (in some vague sense) a "good" reason why this is not the default in R**? If not, **how might I sensibly do so**?

I understand that in practice this is likely a bad idea, if only for reasons of portability, but I'm still curious.

Comment: You shouldn't do this because your code will be confusing for anyone who _does_ understand R

Comment: @akun: I understand that, to be clear, but I'm curious about the reasons for why this is so, as well as how one might change it.

Comment: @HongOoi: I am aware of that, as suggested by the final paragraph, but as I say, I am curious to understand this.

Comment: I feel that this is actually a very interesting idea, especially in the context of converting objects with named elements into data frames and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are times when method-overloading is a good thing; with primitive functions, it is feasible with some classes (e.g., `data.table:::$<-.data.table` and `tibble:::$.tbl_df`), it is not trivial with base classes. In general, I think attempting this is a bad idea.

- One idiomatic way to do this would be to provide an S3 method that supports it, such as `$.numeric`. This would allow you to tightly control use of this method for a specific type of object (in this case, a `numeric` *vector*, does not trigger on `list`s). Unfortunately, because `$` is a primitive function, it does not allow overloading on base R object classes such as `$.numeric`.
- If you're willing to re-class vectors on which you want to apply this, then this *can* be done:

  ```r
  `$.quux` <- function(x, name) x[name]
  vec <- c(a = 1)
  class(vec) <- c("quux", class(vec))
  vec$a
  # a 
  # 1 
  vec$b
  # <NA> 
  #   NA
  ```

  Unfortunately, this requires you to re-`class` any object you want to be able to do this with.
- Another choice would be to override `$` itself:

  ```r
  `$` <- function(x, name) x[deparse(substitute(name))]
  c(a=1)$a
  # a 
  # 1
  ```

  But there are *so many problems* with this: it affects every normal use of `$`, including non-vector arguments (try `mtcars$mpg` and see that it now returns a single-column `data.frame` instead of the normal behavior of a vector) and assignment (`mtcars$mpg <- ...` fails). It is certainly possible to try to catch each and every one of these special cases, but invariably you'll either miss some corner-case, some object type, or cause some otherwise assumed behavior to mis-behave, breaking other things.

While I agree that this behavior might seem a little inconsistent, honestly there comes a time when changing this type of behavior has way too many second-order effects than you can band-aid. (One close analogy to this kind of change could be python2 versus python3: that "transition" started in December 2008 with the first release of python-3, and despite python-2's alleged [end-of-life in Jan 2020](https://pythonclock.org/), it's been neither prompt nor smooth.)